# How important is it not to touch computer hardware like PCBs directly and only handle them by their sides?

Tags: hardware-failure

I've heard that you're only supposed to handle computer hardware like PCBs by their sides and to not touch them directly. However, I've seen experienced techies use their grubby fingers to handle computer hardware without any concern at all even when I tell them about the proper side-handling technique. Is there any real damage or malfunction that could happen because of this?

Comment: Its important.  "Is there any real damage or malfunction that could happen because of this?" - Yes; ESD actually does exist.  Just because "experienced techies" are willing to risk their equipment doesn't mean you should repeat their bad habits.

Answer (score 1):

There is a wide variety of factors that influence this. If you carry some static electrical load you might damage a component permanently. It's usually a good idea to touch something that's grounded beforehand or wear some ESD strap. Another bad idea is to touch contacts directly as you might help oxide build up which would limit conductivity which might lead to unexpected behavior.

That said it always could work without any of those measures.